# manipulating the strings to make new strings with the respective indexes

Tags: java, stringbuilder

> input :have anic eday

```
String[] words = sb.toString().split("//s");
    StringBuilder sbFinal = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<words[0].length() ;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<words.length;j++){
            sbFinal.append(words[j].charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return sbFinal.toString() ;
```

> output : have anic eday

I have a number of strings which I need to convert in the form where a new set of strings are printed ( space seperated ) which are formed by the respective chars of each strings given  .

> desired output : hae and via ecy

for example we have 3 words of 4 chars each , we want 4 words of 3 chars each .

have anic eday =>hae and via ecy

we pick 1st char from all 3 words to make the new first word .

I used the code shown above but it prints the input as output itself .

Comment: So you have x words with y characters each. Do you always want to build y words with x characters each? What is the exact logic to build each of these words?

Comment: So you basically want to take the transpose of a `char[][]` and join it into a `String` delimited by a single character of whitespace?

Comment: yes .it is part of an encryption problem i was trying to solve . I divided problem into modules , this is the final part . But the output as I have shown above is unexpected  . Is my loops logic erroneous ?

Comment: yes but i wanted to look at the problem using stringbuilder @JacobG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although answered, I made up a more similar version to what you have originally designed, just with sysout instead of return, but change to your needs, or just adjust the .split() line:

```
String sb = "have anic eday";
String[] words = sb.split("\\s"); //you need to use BACKWARDSLASH "\\s" to get it to work.
StringBuilder sbFinal = new StringBuilder();


for (int i = 0; i < words[0].length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        sbFinal.append(words[j].charAt(i));
    }
    sbFinal.append(" ");
}

System.out.println(sbFinal.toString());
```

You split with "//s", however " " or "\\s" seems to work perfectly fine.

Comment: the error was due to the split("//s") , thanks a lot .

Comment: im glad that resolved the issue. apparently, people just downvote nowadays.

Comment: but you sir , keep helping beginers like me ! (Y)

Comment: @Instinct Apparently, `sb.split(" ");` and `sb.split("\\s");` should give the same output.

Comment: yes, but OP used forwardslashes "//", which do not. after all, i pointed at the pile that was asked for and gave a working solution and explanation, even if the downvoter wouldve made it different.

Answer (score 2):

Use simple `for` loops and an array:

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "have anic eday ";

        // Split the input.
        String[] words = input.split("\\s");
        int numberOfWords = words.length;
        int wordLength = words[0].length();

        // Prepare the result;
        String[] result = new String[wordLength];

        // Loop over the new words.
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            // Loop over the characters in each new word.
            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfWords; j++) {
                // Initialize the new word, if necessary.
                String word = result[i] != null ? result[i] : "";

                // Append the next character to the new word.
                String newChar = Character.toString(words[j].charAt(i));
                result[i] = word + newChar;
            }
        }

        for (String newWord : result) {
            System.out.println(newWord);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hae
and
via
ecy
```

Comment: Thank you so much but I was looking for error in my code .